# Can I use SPSS's OUTPUT MODIFY to change row header or use Pivoting Trays?

Tags: spss

I only recently learned about the OUTPUT MODIFY command and I'm trying to figure out how to automate some of the menial point-and-click parts of creating reports. One task that I'm failing to figure out is to replace the word "Total" at the bottom of the variable list (bottom row header) with something else.
I tried using several variations of the command below, but it seems it doesn't want to let me modify that part of the table.

```
output modify
 /select tables   /if subtypes=["Report"]  /tablecells select=["Total"] applyto=rowheader replace="XXXX".
```

Is there a way to do this with a piece of syntax? CTRL+H works fine, but by gods, if the 3 second task can be automated, I will spend hours looking for that solution!

Additional questions about the OUTPUT MODIFY command that I wasn't able to figure out myself:

- Can I use it to delete a data column of the table? I only successfully deleted a whole table, not a part of it.
- Can I use it to essentially hide/reorganize aspects of a table, akin to using the Pivoting Trays feature? E.g. hide the "N" and "significance" rows of a correlation table. Or is there a part of the CORRELATIONS command I'm not seeing that genearates only the *r* values? Deleting the rows as a part of the previous question is also an option.
- Can I use it to replace values in table X with corresponding values from table Y? Or is this more of an OMS question?
- What is your favorite use of the OUTPUT MODIFY?

Thanks in advance!